# Fetching data, edit MongoDB Collection before loading webapp? Async, Promises?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, mongoose

I'm using MongoDB and NodeJS and trying to preload my Collection `customers` everytime the site is loaded. I'm emptying it, filling it with empty Documents and finally replacing (if available) any of them with real data from an external source.

I tried using `save()`, but it's giving the error message `'ParallelSaveError' - Can't save() the same doc multiple times in parallel. Document: 3"`. It's not fetching the data before rendering it. This results in missing items in the dashboard, just one or two being displayed. I read something about asynchronous functions and Promises, but I'm not sure how to apply them in my case. How to implement this?

**dbtools.js**

```
var empty = new Customer({
  _id: '',
  name: 'Unused',
  surname: '',
  birthday: '',
  deathday: '',
  phx: false,
  ntw: false,
  gender: 'empty'
});

module.exports = {
  getCustomers: async function() {
    // Fill array with empty slots
    slots = [empty, empty, empty];

    // Clearing collection
    Customer.deleteMany({}, function(err) {});

    // Looping through Array, add each Document
    for (i = 0; i < slots.length; i++) {
      slots[i]._id = i+1;

      mongoose.connection.collection('customers').insert(slots[i]);
      // or
      slots[i].save(function (err) { if (err) return handleError(err); });
    }
    // Updating with external data
    ..
  }
}
```

**router.js**

```
var tools = require('./dbtools.js');
..
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
  tools.getCustomers();
        Customer.find({}, function (err, customers) {
    if (err) return handleError(err);
    res.render('dashboard', {
      title: 'Overview',
      customers: customers
    });
  });
});
..
```

Comment: Refer this.  [link](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/8000)

Comment: @MukulDev tried to wrap it in `try/catch`, as vkarpov15 over there suggested, but I still get the [same result](https://pastebin.com/raw/d5dyKYNB)..

Answer (score 0):

Based on the `async` in the getCustomers function that there are Promises/async calls within the function. If so, any functions that call that funciton needs an `await`in front in order to catch the async callback.

```
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    try {
        const customers = await tools.getCustomers();
        res.render(...);
    } catch (e) {
        return handleError(err);
    }
});
```

Please tell me if that helps